# How do you concatenate a single cell value with all values in a select column? [Google Sheets]

Tags: google-sheets

I've got 2 columns, A has checkboxes and B has names, and I've been using
`=query(A1:B10,"select B where A",0)`. I'm trying to find a way to concatenate the results from B with a single value in C1. So if C1 has "-11" the results would be something like John-11, Dan-11, Roger-11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do everything in one go with FILTER:

```
=ifna(filter(B1:B10&C1,A1:A10))
```

N.B. '&' doesn't need to be wrapped in ARRAYFORMULA as it would normally need to be for an array operation like this because FILTER natively only accepts arrays (so effectively automatically applies ARRAYFORMULA to any scalar functions within it). The outer IFNA traps the #N/A error that results if no checkboxes are TRUE.